# Body not covering the whole page with reactjs/react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

my problem is just as the title says I have a gradient background but it is not covering the whole page as you can see here and you'll notice that underneath my navbar there is a slightly different color that I'd like to fix as well

[image]
[Result from using height:100vh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDGv4.png)

Here is my css code

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background: #bdc3c7;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #2c3e50, #bdc3c7);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2c3e50, #bdc3c7); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.CarouselIndex{
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.navbar-brand {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  padding: 7px 14px;
}

.LogoHeader{
  color: white;
}

.Footer{
  background-color: black;
  position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 color:white;
  border-color: black;
  margin-bottom: auto;
 text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.aboutimg{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}

.textarea{
  resize: vertical;
}
```

Comment: Typically the body will have a min-height. You'll need to add more info for both parts of your question. Specifically the HTML used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will work when you add `height: 100vh` to the `.App` class. Is this navbar imported from a framework?

Comment: If I use height :100vh it just goes all the way down even if I dont have any content I just added an image to the post so you can see. The navbar is imported from react-boostrap

Comment: So you just want to make the footer stick to the bottom? Like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515142/how-to-make-a-sticky-footer-in-react)? Or you want to make the gradient full page without affecting any other elements?