# Sticky footer for react with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, react-router

I need a really clean and simple solution for an issue I always run into, that I can continue using in other projects as well. I need a sticky footer that works with react-router-dom. I can't seem to get it working. My App.js looks like this:

```
  <div>
    <Header loaded={loaded} />
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/about"
        render={props => <About loaded={loaded} {...props} />}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        render={props => <MainPage loaded={loaded} {...props} />}
      />
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
  </div>
```

How would you go about making the footer sticky? Thanks!

Comment: try this example -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515142/how-to-make-a-sticky-footer-in-react

Comment: That example uses a fixed footer, not a sticky footer. I need a footer that sits below the content on pages with more content than 100% height, but is fixed to the bottom on pages with less than 100% height of the content. Does that make sense?

Comment: use minHeight property in each route component...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a way better solution for working with a sticky footer around react-router-dom using flex-box.

App.js:

```
  <div id="container">
    <Header loaded={loaded} />
    <div id="main-content">
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/about"
          render={props => <About loaded={loaded} {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={props => <MainPage loaded={loaded} {...props} />}
        />
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
```

app.css

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#main-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

I hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. I tried yours because it was the most top layer and simple. I didn't have to edit my footer. I just added the css code inside my content and footer classes. Thanks!